# How to perform a query in Firebase's Cloud Firestore

Tags: firebase, nosql, google-cloud-firestore

I followed the doc [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) on how to write a query but I am not getting any data from it. The database is already populated with the example provided by the doc

Below is my code

```
var db = firebase.firestore();

var citiesRef = db.collection("cities");
var query = citiesRef.where("state", "==", "CA");

query.get().then(function(doc) {
if (doc.exists) {
    console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
} else {
    console.log("No such document!");
}
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error getting document:", error);
});
```

It works fine if I didn't put any queries on it. For example (also from the doc):

```
var docRef = db.collection("cities").doc("SF");

docRef.get().then(function(doc) {
    if (doc.exists) {
        console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
    } else {
        console.log("No such document!");
    }
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error getting document:", error);
});
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The difference in your two requests is that in the second case you are retrieving one document which gives you a [`DocumentSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot) which has the `exists` property and the `data()` method.

In your not working example you do a query, which gives you a [`QuerySnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot) that has to be handled differently from a `DocumentSnapshot`. Instead of a single document you get a list/collection of documents. You can check if data has been retrieved using the `empty` or `size` properties, and then go through the results using the `forEach` method or going through the `docs` array:

```
var db = firebase.firestore();

var citiesRef = db.collection("cities");
var query = citiesRef.where("state", "==", "CA");

query.get().then(function(results) {
  if(results.empty) {
    console.log("No documents found!");   
  } else {
    // go through all results
    results.forEach(function (doc) {
      console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
    });

    // or if you only want the first result you can also do something like this:
    console.log("Document data:", results.docs[0].data());
  }
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error getting documents:", error);
});
```